# How to implement complex SQL statements in cosmos DB, such as JOIN IN and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have some items in Cosmos DB.

In Master collection:

`{
    "id": "12a8af32-c8df-41f8-a253-37c900199113",
    "BuildingAddr": "123",
    "province": "jiangsu",
    "city": "shanghai",
    "UnitNumber": "F8N7S777"
}`

In Callback collection:

`{
    "id": "818e6f3f-60fb-4c38-926f-296e410dfe19",
    "UnitNumber": "R2NT3670",
    "RequestTime": 1578542878,
    "status": 1,
    "StorageTime": 15785428456,
}`

I had tried like this:

`SELECT Master.city, COUNT(Callback.id) AS errorNumber FROM Callback
JOIN Master IN Callback.UnitNumber WHERE Callback.UnitNumber IN ("F8NKH287", "F8NKH288") 
AND Callback.status IN (1, 4, 5) AND Master.province = "jiangsu"
GROUP BY call.city`

I want to select items in Callback which Callback.UnitNumber = Master.UnitNumber and Callback.UnitNumber in given UnitNumber, and Callback.status in given status, and Master.province equals given province, then group by Master.city.
Too much normal SQL statements doesn't work in cosmos db. That makes me having a headache, and now I feel so desperate! Please help me, thanks!

Comment: you have to execute sql cross collections in cosmos db?

Comment: Understand...but cosmos db collections can't be queried across. The collections under db are independent individuals. If you want to unit data from 2 collections, you have to query them and aggregate them by yourself.

Comment: I see. But I can't figured it out why microsoft made a very difficult database...

Comment: Well,i can't represent anyone but i think microsoft can't always compatible other services, it has to create it's own core service to build advantages so MS made own no-sql db :cosmos db which acts as important role in azure family. If you have any difficulty or questions, you could post here or contact with azure support team. All guys are glad to assist you.

Comment: Back to your requirement,you may confused about the differences between relational database and non-relational database so that you even want to query data cross collections. That's illegal. You could follow @Mark's links to get some concepts about them,maybe.

Comment: I have contacted support team for three times.This time I ask  them that why the same sql

Comment: I have contacted support team for three times.This time I ask  them that why the same sql ran normally in database resource manager(web) but didn't work in the project.They response slowly. Here is the sql:
SELECT COUNT(Master.BuildingAddr) AS buildingNumber FROM Master WHERE Master.UnitNumber IN ("123", "234").
If I have any way to avoid using cross query, I won't be so desperated.

Comment: It seems that stackoverflow don't want us to discuss in comments, how about we talk privately?

Answer (score 1):

Cosmos DB is not a relational database and does not support ANSI SQL constructs like cross collection joins. If you are new to this type of database I recommend starting with this set of docs to understand key concepts for designing for a NoSQL datastore.

[NoSQL vs Relational](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/relational-nosql)

[Modeling data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data)

[How to model and partition data - real world example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example)

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty answer !

Comment: I want to learn it step by step, but time is not enough.Otherwise I won't feel desperate......

Comment: @Mark  Thank you anyway! I'll learn from your advice when I'm not chasing time!

Comment: Hi John. I would encourage you to read these articles and also find other content on how to model for NoSQL databases now rather than waiting. These concepts are not optional when it comes to using this type of database. If you don't understand these concepts and apply them early in your design you risk designing a database that will not perform well or scale. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry for not response you in such a long time. Work made me busy. Follow your words, I could not change the db design or data structure, because they were designed by my customer. Now I'm trapped by cosmos db again because I can't get the latest data . I cannot use the TOP syntax to obtain the latest data of multiple elevators at the same time. I can only use the sorting syntax to obtain the TOP data of one elevator and then query the next elevator. This caused my program to query very slowly. 
It's sad.